# pgfkeys error on 1.14 but not on 1.15

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following latex MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{
      xtick pos=bottom, ytick pos=right,
      ylabel near ticks,
      yticklabel style={xshift=-6pt}}
% \expandafter\show\csname ver@pgfplots.sty\endcsname
\begin{document} \ \end{document}
```

When I run this on my machine which has pgfplots 1.15 (and TL17) (I found the version number using `\expandafter\show\csname ver@pgfplots.sty\endcsname`) I get no errors.

However, when compiling the same file on arxiv which seems to have pgfplots 1.14 (and TL16), I get the error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'bottom' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/xtickpos'.
```

Removing the offending key-value `xtick pos=bottom` resolves the issue, but I would like to understand the reasons behind it.

I understand that `/pgfplots/xtickpos=bottom` might be not implemented in 1.14, but then I thought that since I am using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` on my machine, the same error should appear.

Any insight on this is much appreciated. I cannot revert pgfplots on my machine to 1.14 because I do not have admin access.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example, then others with access to older installation might help test this.

Comment: I'm not sure how the compat works, but can confirm that the MWE works on TL19, 18 and 17 and fails with the error on TL16 (which I think is the version arxiv uses). Perhaps you should just make your tikz image using the `standalone` class and then just include it as a pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in the [PGFPlots ChangeLog line 80](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/master/tree/doc/latex/pgfplots/ChangeLog) the entry

> - fixed bug 105 [manual] `xticklabel pos=upper` is not documented
>         in fact, some of the documented positions for `xtick pos` where
>         unavailable.

And there (https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/105/) everything important is documented.

The summary is, that the key--value in question (`xtick pos=bottom`) neither was documented fully nor was implemented fully. Thus, this was done for version 1.15.

---

The `compat` key works that way that it only changes stuff that previously worked **different**. But here no behavior **changed**. Here (just) a missing feature was implemented and now just **works**, regardless of the `compat` key.

Comment: These are the kinds of answers that tend to cost some time to do the research, and typically do not give much points. I only can give +1.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, many thanks. This time it was not that hard, because I found that bug myself **and** I could remember it. Thus, it was quite easy to find the relevant pieces ;)